# React i18n - "t" function doesn't accept string variables (typescript)? "No overload matches this call"

Tags: typescript, i18next, react-typescript, react-i18next

anyone familiar with this error:
[code with error message][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbJvu.png

```
{t(`${settingType}` as const)}
```

error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(key: TemplateStringsArray | Normalize<{
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What type does `settingsType` have? It looks like `t` requires you to pass specific strings in, not any string.

Comment: https://react.i18next.com/latest/typescript#type-errors

Comment: @Nicolas 
`GeneralSettings = 'generalSettings',
   PermissionManagement = 'permissionManagement',
   AccountDepartments = 'accountDepartments',
   ShiftManagement = 'shiftManagement',
   OrderTimesManagement = 'orderTimesManagement',`

Comment: @adrai i did that :) `{t(`${settingType}` as const)}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: change `t(str)` to

```
t(str as unknown as TemplateStringsArray)
```

I personally created a helper function to do so, which I recommend.

Comment: this results in the same error for me

Comment: @ChumiestBucket Interesting as that solution changes the variable's type from string so i dont understand.
Mind sharing a photo?

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem and [Adri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71896191/11809162) answer helped me.

If you want, this is the function I've done:

```js
export const normalizeKey = (key: string) => key as unknown as TemplateStringsArray;
```